# Symfony2 Session values

Tags: php, symfony, session

Where can i see the stores `SESSION` values in Symfonry2 Framework.
Where can i Find the Error Log File [Location]

Thanks.

Comment: try `var_dump($log);` to check if its empty or it is an array or object. `What do you mean by the below Symfony Controller Action Code.?` [Read documentation here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

Comment: Hi `get('hoursTransferred');` what is the meaning of this in above Code.?

Comment: it will read value from session if the session value is set or not.. if it's set it will return value , else it will return empty value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Symfony VarDumper Component:

dump($log);

Comment: I guess you refer to Symfony VarDumper component, and the function then is dump($log)